# Theano is throwing Segmentation fault

Tags: python, segmentation-fault, theano

I have a `Theano` code which is using batches of data. When I am increasing the batch size, it is throwing me the SegFault error. It is working perfectly fine upto `batch size = 750`. But `increasing` it to `1000` is throwing me error. I also checked that it is using only `50MB of GPU memory` at any time. But I have `128MB GPU memory` on my system. Can anyone help me here to debug the issue.

Comment: How are you measuring GPU memory use? Be aware that the GPU driver and Theano both have some overheads that use some GPU memory. 128MB is a very small amount of GPU memory and those overheads could easily be in the range of 78MB.

Comment: Is memory use linear in the batch size? e.g. if you measure memory use for batch sizes `100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700` and plotted the results, do the points line up in a straight line? If not, and you extrapolate to `batch size = 1000`, does it exceed 128MB?

Comment: It is always showing 50MB

Comment: Do we have any flag for memory?

Answer (score 0):

You can profile Theano's memory use by enabling the `profile` and `profile_memory` configuration flags. See the [documentation](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/profiling.html) for more details.

There is also more information on Python/Theano memory management [here](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/python-memory-management.html).